# unable to serialize json array

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary

I am somewhat new to working with API's and am receiving a graphconnection is not serializable error when trying to json.dumps an api response. The response looks to be a json array however, when i run Type(api_response) nothing is output.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried `Type(api_response)`

```py
api_response = api_instance.graph_user_group_members_list(group_id, content_type, accept,limit=limit, skip=skip, x_org_id=x_org_id)
#pprint(api_response)

data = json.dumps(api_response)
```

I would like to convert the api_response to python dict format so that I can use the json values....

I am receiving this error

```py
TypeError: Object of type GraphConnection is not JSON serializable
```

This is the output if I print api_response

```
[{'_from': None, 'to': {'id': '', 'type': 'user'}}, {'_from': None, 
'to': {'id': '', 'type': 'user'}}]
```

Comment: Why don't you use api_response directly without doing json.dumps(api_response)? you just have to iterate over it and you can use json fields from your response

Comment: Use json.dumps(obj, default=func) where func is a function that returns a serializable version of your object. In short, write a function that returns a dict representation of your whole object.

Comment: `json` module from standard library only deals with dictionaries and lists. If you print api_response, it's just a string that can be anything (it invokes `__str__` method). In this case the string is already json-like

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because of the brackets around the json object. The data within the curly braces is valid json. Try to index the api_response (like `jsonObject = api_response[0]`) to get the 'first element' of the api response object.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was able to find the solution by using ([ob.**dict** for ob in api_response]). Still think I am missing some knowledge surrounding how json.dumps works.